# How Can I Find the slow running statement/query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to find the more CPU pressure statement in a slow running query. I know there is a code to find a slow running statement inside a query. My goal is to add option(maxdop 1) after that statement.

Comment: Google `SQL Server Execution Plan`

Comment: Brent Ozar has some really helpful scripts for things like this - look into Blitz

Answer (score 0):

Best way to investigate query slowness is with the SQL Server execution plan:
https://developer.rackspace.com/blog/understanding-a-sql-server-execution-plan/

Another way of speeding up your database (depending on your situation) might be to rebuild indexes: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/reorganize-and-rebuild-indexes?view=sql-server-2017